# __str__ wrapper in custom Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, decorator, wrapper

Why does the below code print `error msg` instead of `ABC\nerror msg`?

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """ABC"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.__str__ = self._wrapper(self.__str__)
    def _wrapper(self, f):
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.__doc__ + '\n' + f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _inner

print(CustomException('error msg'))
```

Comment: `__str__` is called on the class `CustomException`, not on the individual object. You're only changing `__str__` on the individual object `self`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you attempt the wrap-and-replace of ``__str__`` instead of just re-implementing the ``__str__`` *method* and calling ``super().__str__()``?

Comment: @khelwood true, I totally missed that, thanks for a hint. MisterMiyagi, no, no reason other than overcomplicating things :) I'll do it your way, thanks as well!

Comment: @khelwood *`__str__` is called on the class CustomException, not on the individual object.* I'm a bit confused. Isn't `__str__` an instance method?

Comment: @TheScore It is an instance method in the sense that an instance is its first argument; but it is looked up on the class, and called passing the instance as the first argument. Generally that's the way magic methods are called.

Comment: @khelwood Like this `Foo.__str__(obj)`, right? I might be wrong but all instance methods are called this way by python, right? i.e. `instance.method(*args, **kwargs)` is called by python as `Foo.method(instance, *args, **kwargs)` I don't know where I read this.

Comment: @TheScore If you do `x.method()` then you're looking up the bound `method` on the object `x` and then calling it. If you do `cls.method(x)` then you are looking up the `method` on the class and calling it with `x` as the first argument. They are not equivalent if you have set `x.method` to a different value from the one defined in the class.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah got it. Thanks

Comment: Instance methods are the return value of a *class* attribute with a `__get__` method. `CustomException` doesn't have an attribute named `__str__`, let alone one with a `__get__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations backed by special methods usually explicitly look up the special method as a proper method not just as a callable attribute. Concretely, instead of `self.__str__` the interpreter roughly looks at `type(self).__str__.__get__(self, type(self))` – i.e. [a descriptor `__str__`  on the class to be bound with the instance.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) To override a special method, it is thus necessary to override the class' descriptor instead of the instance' attribute.

This can be done by a) declaring the special method as a slot, which handles the `type(self).__str__` part, and b) assigning a function, which handles the `__get__(self, type(self))` part.

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    """ABC"""
    __slots__ = ("__str__",)  # <<< magic

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        # vvv self.__str__ is the class' slot
        self.__str__ = self._wrapper(super().__str__)
        #                            AAA real __str__ lives on the super class
    def _wrapper(self, f):
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.__doc__ + '\n' + f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _inner

print(CustomException('error msg'))
```

Note that since every instance behaves the same in this case, it is advisable to just define a new `__str__` method in practice.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the Exception class for now. Consider this:

```py
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'A'

obj = A()
print(obj)
obj.__str__ = lambda x: 'B'
print(obj)
A.__str__ = lambda x: 'B'
print(obj)
```

output:

```
A
A   # Not B !
B
```

Dunder methods' lookup is different in Python. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup):

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only
> guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in
> the object’s instance dictionary.

What you want to achieve is:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """ABC"""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__doc__ + '\n' + super().__str__()


print(CustomException('error msg'))
```

output:

```
ABC
error msg
```

Answer (score 1):

As per *[@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood)*'s reply in the comments this code works as intended:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """ABC"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.__class__.__str__ = self._wrapper(self.__str__)
    def _wrapper(self, f):
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.__doc__ + '\n' + f()
        return _inner
```

but I ended up with this equivalent ([*@MisterMiyagi*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi)):

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """ABC"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__doc__ + '\n' + super().__str__()
```

Comment: The first example doesn't really work as intended, as each instance of `CustomException` you create will change how `__str__` works for *all* instances.

Comment: @chepner how can this issue be addressed?

Comment: By properly defining an instance method named `__str__`, rather than creating an instance attribute named `__str__`.

Comment: If you also want the first example to work(which I don't recommend), you should change `self._wrapper(self.__str__)` to `self._wrapper(super().__str__)` , otherwise the more you create `CustomException('error msg')` object the more you get `ABC` in the output. test it